# Startup.cs file doesn't have the Configure() method present, but the ConfigureServices() method is present. is this a standalone app?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm reviewing this app with no documentation whatsoever, and I'm also not very familiar with C# and .NET. I need to figure out if this is some sort of a web app or and an app that exposes APIs or just a standalone app like an SDK.

Upon checking, there seems to be no routes configured. Also, some tutorials say that the web settings are to be placed in the Configure() method but it doesn't exist in the Startup.cs file. Does this mean this is not some sort of web app?

Comment: It's very likely it's an ASP.NET app.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.